# Dojo Drag and drop: how to format a dropped item?

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

I'm using Dojo trying to build an application with dojo's dnd. I've looked around for an answer to this problem but I'm just not sure how to accomplish this. I have a Source object in which there are a bunch of products formatted with html/css in a certain way. When I drag these objects to my Target object, the dropped item still looks the same as before. I want to format it differently after being dropped. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this via passing a `creator` function ref to your Source object.

Assuming you have dojo 1.3 and can use `dojo.create.`

In your JS:

```
function myCreator( item, hint ) {
   var myDiv = dojo.create( 'div', { innerHTML: item.name });

   if (hint == 'avatar') {
      // create your avatar if you want
      myDiv.innerHTML = 'I'm an avator of ' + item.name;
   }
   return {node: myDiv, data: item, type: item.type};
}
```

Then in your HTML (div or whatever):

```
<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" creator="myCreator"></div>
```

If you want to create the `Source` item programmatically, just pass in the creator like so:

```
var dnd = new dojo.dnd.Source(someNode, { creator: myCreator });
```

I used `item.name` in my example above.  This all depends on your item though so you will probably want to use a different field.

An excellent walk through of creating a `dojo.dnd` page is on [the SitePen blog](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/10/dojo-drag-and-drop-1/).

Comment: Thanks Seth -- I was using the creator function for dnd Source, but didn't realize you could use it for Target too. Thanks!

Comment: Ah...yeah.  dojo is sneaky that way.  Target is a subclass of Source.

Answer (score 0):

```
topic.subscribe("/dnd/drop", function(source, nodes, copy, target) {

    target.forInSelectedItems(function(item, id) {
        //alert(document.getElementById(id));
        if (document.getElementById(id).innerHTML == "something from your source") {
            //create what you want, and add it to id
        }
    }
}
```